# Is it possible to show the computed/Methods calculated values from one component to another component in Vue Js?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

**Parent Component**

```html
 <template>     
     <ChildComponent @send-message="handleSendMessage" />    
 </template>
```

**Parent Component Script**

```js
export default {      
    methods: { 
        handleSendMessage(event, value) { 
            console.log('From the child:', value);
        }    
    }    
}
```

**child Component**

```js
export default {     
    props: {
        method: { type: Function },   
    },  
    computed:{ 
        rep_9100_3() {
            return parseInt(this.rep_6000_3) - this.decutable_allowance
        },   
    },
    mounted() {  
        this.$emit('send-message', this.rep_9100_3);   
    }   
}
```

Comment: Could you make it more clear what the structure of your app is. Is `nav-bar` a parent to `report`? How are they connected, if at all?

Comment: <!-- Parent -->
<template>
  <ChildComponent @send-message="handleSendMessage" />
</template>

Comment: // Parent
export default {
  methods: {
    handleSendMessage(event, value) {
      // Our event handler gets the event, as well as any
      // arguments the child passes to the event
      console.log('From the child:', value);
    }
  }
}

Comment: Could you add it to the question so it's clear :)

Comment: And in the child component we emit the event:

// Child
export default {
  props: {
    method: { type: Function },
  },
  data() {
    return { value: 'I am the child.' };
  },
  mounted() {
    // Instead of calling the method we emit an event
    this.$emit('send-message', this.value);
  }
}

Comment: Actually i want to emit the bundle of values extracted from database  which is computed in report with mathematical function i want to display computed values in side bar component

Comment: Right, so can you update your question with all this information. Would make giving you an answer at lot easier.

Comment: i update the question

Answer (score 0):

Yes you simply need to change `handleSendMessage(event, value)` to `handleSendMessage(value)`.

One extra thing to note. It's could practice to pass a `radix` value when using `parseInt`:

```js
parseInt(this.rep_6000_3, 10)
```

Comment: sorry this.decutable_allowance is also a parentInt(this.decutable_allowance) then how i write this to access this ??

Comment: the same `parseInt(this.decutable_allowance, 10)`. (not parentInt, but parseInt)

Comment: can you please more simply why i pass radix to it ??

Comment: It's the base in mathematical numeral systems. So base `10` is usually what most of our daily mathematics uses. You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt